# How to get the final php code to be executed replacing all the require and include with their code

Tags: php

First let me apologize if this question was answered before, I just don't seem to find the proper terms to search for it.

### The context

I'm viewing some complex PHP code with a lot of `require` in it, it is kind of ineffective and time consuming to search for a `function`'s or `variable`'s definition through all the multiple level tree of files included in the current file.

### The desired result :

so I'm wondering if a function exists that does the following:

- Remove all those `requires`
- Replace them with their code recursively
- Output it on the browser or return it to a variable

In a nutshell, a function that prints the final PHP code to be executed.

### The question :

Is there such a function? if yes, what is its name?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the code which is going to be executed because inclusion of code can be done at run-time, based on variables whose values you don't know before running the code.

What you can do is archive all the possible code to be executed, and pack it up as a phar archive.

Using modern tools, that could mean using `composer archive`.

More information available here https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#archive

Besides, it would go against the ecosystem: in modern PHP applications, you use autoloading. Which means that even in projects with millions of lines of code and hundred of thousands of files, there is only one include/require statement.